# Any New TTS libraries for IOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, text-to-speech

I currently use Flite tts in my app and the male voice works just fine. But my client wants the female voice to work just as well. There is a notorious difference between the processing times in both voices (Female stl Voice has a delay of 2 seconds more than the default voice). The other obstacle is that the TTS has to work offline so DragonMobile and iSpeech are not an option. 
In your opinions, whats the best TTS library with small delays for iOS?
Has anybody seen a newer/modified version of flite 1.4?
I realize I either find an optimized version for Flite or change my library. 
I have been looking at different posts and most of them are from a long time so I'm hoping something new and better is out there. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Go for politepix openears tts. its an updates version of Flite with the combination of some other tts engines. Offline tts synthesizer as same as Flite. uses the same voices provided by Flite. please have a look at here

http://www.politepix.com/openears